# Pattern capture with different token position / offset

Tags: elasticsearch, search, indexing

From the elastic search doc

> Note: All tokens are emitted in the same position, and with the same character offsets. This means, for example, that a match query for john-smith_123@foo-bar.com that uses this analyzer will return documents containing any of these tokens, even when using the and operator. Also, when combined with highlighting, the whole original token will be highlighted, not just the matching subset. For instance, querying the above email address for "smith" would highlight:
>   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-capture-tokenfilter.html

Does there is a way to generate those token with different position/offset ?

Given the example that elastic search provide, I want to be able to search on `com` AND `john` but as I understand, it will match all the email that contain `com` or `john` because they will be consider as the same position.

(In my case I want to do that for code analysis, so similar as the 2 second example they gave)

```
      "analysis" : {
         "filter" : {
            "code" : {
               "type" : "pattern_capture",
               "preserve_original" : true,
               "patterns" : [
                  "(\\p{Ll}+|\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}+|\\p{Lu}+)",
                  "(\\d+)"
               ]
            }
         },
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, but it looks like what you are trying to do is:  Make sure the indexing tokenizer breaks the input as you expect, meaning there's a 'com' token and 'john' token. You can check the tokenizer by running an analyze request: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html

After the input get analyzed and tokenized as expected you can run the John AND com query, and it should work as expected.

Comment: Indeed, in most of the case what you describe is true. But the problem is with the pattern_capture token filter It is not how it works. I want to achieve what you describe, but, this filter will split correctly the token. And so com and john will be correctly index. However, their position/offset are the same meaning that the behavior you describe is not possible. From the doc: `return documents containing any of these tokens, even when using the and operator`

Comment: This sound strange. I never encountered this. maybe you can run a regex query, having both 'john' and 'com' in the same regex, will force their location and existence,

Comment: did you find a solution? @Ay_mhwan